# Can't get text from dropdown options

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_desktop_currency_selector\"]/div")).click();
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_desktop_currency_selector\"]/div/ul//li"));

System.out.println(list.size());

for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
}
```

**Output:**

 3 
EUR €

I'm need to get the text from items in dropdown, my code can find all li elements and print number of them, but when I'm trying to print the visible text from them but I'm getting only text from the first option :(

I would be very grateful for a hint...

**Part of page source:**

```
<div id="_desktop_currency_selector">
  <div class="currency-selector dropdown js-dropdown">
    <span>Currency:</span>
    <span class="expand-more _gray-darker hidden-sm-down" data-toggle="dropdown">UAH ₴</span>
    <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="hidden-sm-down">
      <i class="material-icons expand-more">&#xE5C5;</i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu hidden-sm-down" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
              <li >
          <a title="European EURO" rel="nofollow" href="http://wasd.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=2" class="dropdown-item">EUR €</a>
        </li>
              <li  class="current" >
          <a title="Ukrainian UAH" rel="nofollow" href="http://wasd.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=1" class="dropdown-item">UAH ₴</a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a title="Dollar USA" rel="nofollow" href="http://wasd.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=3" class="dropdown-item">USD $</a>
        </li>
          </ul>
    <select class="link hidden-md-up">
              <option value="http://wasd.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=2">EUR €</option>
              <option value="http://wasd.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=1" selected="selected">UAH ₴</option>
              <option value="http://wasd.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=3">USD $</option>
          </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is the output of `System.out.println("index: i=  "+i+":  "+list.get(i).getText());` ? Seems your code is right but the text is blank/empty.

Comment: Please add html source code or URL.

Comment: @ruhul this is what I get:

index: i=  0:  EUR €
index: i=  1:  (empty)
index: i=  2:  (empty)

Comment: @pburgr added into the footer of the question

Comment: @misha07380 When the dropdown expands and you inspect the element with text as **EUR €** which element among `<a>` and `<option>` gets highlighted?

Comment: @DebanjanB 

This one become highlighted when I open dropdown:

<i class="material-icons expand-more"></i>


And when I going over options with my cursor one of this become highlighted too:

<a title="Евро" rel="nofollow" href="http://xxx.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=2" class="dropdown-item">EUR €</a>

<a title="Украинская гривна" rel="nofollow" href="http://xxx.com.ua/ru/search?order=product.price.desc&amp;s=dress&amp;SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=1" class="dropdown-item">UAH ₴</a>

etk

Answer (score 3):

I've added `a` tag at the end which seems working.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_desktop_currency_selector\"]/div/ul/li/a"));
```

Also if you just want to print the `text` inside `<option>` tag use this:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_desktop_currency_selector\"]/div/select/option"));
```

Both of this produce same result.

Output:

```
3
EUR €
UAH ₴
USD $
```

Comment: Better to avoid those long xpaths. Even small change on the web can break test. Using simple locators make test more 'web-change proof'.

Comment: The first one with a still print only first option (Euro), the second one print nothing :(

Comment: well in that case, there may be some thing else that is causing this problem. The html code you provided, produce this result. You may try with latest salenium drivers and also check if there are other things happens when you actually make a click on `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_desktop_currency_selector\"]/div")).click();
`

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"_desktop_currency_selector\"]/div")).click();` try disabling this line first.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // preprare emtpy list
    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    // get the dropdown element
    WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.className("link hidden-md-up"));
    
    // get dropdown options
    List<WebElement> options = dropDown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    
    // collect texts
    for (WebElement option: options) {
        texts.add(option.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Exit code and content in `List<String> texts` are two different things.